# JQuery fadeIn(), проблема с затемненеием

Tags: jquery

Есть `#vhod` и `#sign`. При нажатии на `#sign` плавно появляется форма для входа на сайт. Вот код который её вызывает.

```js
document.getElementById('sign').onclick = function() {
  $('#vhod').fadeIn();
 }
```

Так же есть идея с затемнением, при появлении формы все остальное на заднем плане должно затемнятся, вот код

```css
#shadow {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
```

Всё это вместе (и форма входа и затемнение) при тыке на `#sign` должно появляться плавно, как это сделать? Код вызывающий плавное появление формы на затемнение вместе не действует.

Comment: transition наверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что вы имели ввиду но скорее всего это

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 1s background;
}

.bg:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">Блаблабла</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за работу, я уже разобрался сам, плюсик поставлю :) Я имел в виду что при нажатии на кнопку появляется форма входа, а все сзади затемняется.